# Do I need a backer rod?

Tags: waterproofing, sealing, cement, joints

I need to make a water tight joint between the garage wall and the pavement:[image]
[image]

I have cleaned out the debris from the gap and blasted it with water to remove all the loose little things.

Now, I have bought a [sealant](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Sikaflex-10-1-fl-oz-Self-Leveling-Sealant-91065/202527281) and want to apply it.

The problem that I'm seeing is that the floor of the gap is not even. Sometimes it's like 1.5 inches deep (where there were plants that I pulled out) and sometimes it's 1/2 inch deep:

[image]

How do I make it more even? Do I use a backer rod? If so, do I lay a continuous backer rod everywhere or only in the places where the gap is deep and leave the naked soil where it's shallow?

Can I apply the [sealant](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Sikaflex-10-1-fl-oz-Self-Leveling-Sealant-91065/202527281) on the soil directly (where it's shallow)?

Thanks kindly for you help.
Jenia

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should stuff backer rod in where the depth exceeds 1/2", to conserve your sealant. That self-leveling sealant will flow/drop to the bottom of the opening rather than bridge the gap. You would get around 12' of fill from a single tube with a bead exactly 1/2" wide by 1/2" deep, much less than that if you don't fill it.

Comment: Okay. Just to make sure: where it's shallow, I don't put in a backer rod? I just apply to sealant on top of the soil?

Comment: Yes, that should be fine. Tell me, is that wall discoloration due to rain water splashing from that tar/bitumen/asphalt surface at grade? Perhaps a couple of coats of quality exterior paint can help cover that.

Comment: Okay, thanks!!.
The discoloration, it's due to the water splashing. Why, is it bad for the wall-cement? Is it only aesthetics or is it actually damaging?

Comment: Just wanted to confirm that it's not some nasty mold or mildew; if it's asphalt stains it is harmless, just aesthetics.

Comment: Hi @Jimmy Fix-it. Tell me please, can I put on the joint now given the fact that it'll rain tonight or tomorrow?

Comment: Dries in 2 hours, full cure takes longer though. can you put a tarp over it or something? I think a little moisture won't be an issue but a flood might be.